# taking mod from every iteration in factorial computing in c++ to not get a number overflow

Tags: c++, math, factorial, modulo

So, I'm now learning competitive programming, and the topic was "modular arithmetic". It's said that you can use (a*b) % c = ((a % c) * (b % c)) % c
and the book tells I can compute a factorial using it without number overflows. But in the example it's said that you can take mod of every operation like this:

```
long long x = 1;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    x = (x*i) % m; // a mod number of some kind
}
cout << x % m << '\n';
```

so, the question is: isn't it better to use it like ((x % c) * (i % c)) % c ? So we won't risk to get an "i" number overflow?

Comment: In this particular case, you have `x % m = x` and generally `i % m = i` (if n < m). If `n > = m` the result is 0.

Comment: fwiw, this is not a magic way to calculate the factorial without overflow. You only get the remainder of the factorial modulo `m`.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818
i know right? it's stated in some problems that if the answer is too big, you don't need to print the exact answer, only some info about it. for example the last digit

Comment: I wonder if one could devise a kind of "spigot" algorithm to generate the digits one at a time, either most significant to least significant or vice versa. Arithmetic mod 10 gives you the least significant digit. I guess dividing by 10 and applying mod 10 gives the second-least, right? Maybe there's a way to formalize this for all digits? (Of course one can work mod 2^32 or something but I think in principal it's the same.)

Answer (score 0):

> isn't it better to use it like `((x % c) * (i % c)) % c` ?

In the example, does `m`'s value fit in 32-bit integer?

If it is true, the value of `x` and `i` are also 32-bit, which means there is no overflow in just one multiplication as `x` can contain a 64-bit integer. So it is safe.

If it is not, even if we replace the calculation with `((x % m * (i % m)) % m`, it still could overflow as `x % m` could be bigger than 32-bit integer. So I don't think it is the case.

So both way works. And your way wouldn't change time complexity of your algorithm. However it has no advantage, just more calculation and more to type :)

---

And I would like to mention one more:

> the book tells I can compute a factorial using it without number overflows.

No we can compute a factorial modulo `m` with that way.
In competitive programming, most of the problems avoid the issue that the answer gets too big with this way. So we can always compute an arithmetic operation at a constant time(no big integers).

Comment: I ment, "i" can become too big, so getting a modulo (like 10 or so) of it would give me the last digit last digit of the number and the answer will be the same. And there are still some problems which state that the answer can become too big, and you need to take a modulo of stated P.

Comment: I'm not sure if we are talking about the same thing... Even if `i` gets bigger it is still 32bit and the value of `x` always fits in 32bit, as long as `m` is 32-bit. However `x`'s type is 64bit so it guarantees no overflow for a single "32bit * 32bit" calculation, so overflowing never happens. So the book's example is correct as well as what you are saying.